# How to manage rate limit for API calls from thousands of users

Tags: android, api

A free API key has a set rate limit, this includes premium ones as well. How do commercial Android apps get enough rate limit to handle thousands of requests? Do I set up my own server and API (that access that API) to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to do anything limit our API rate that the rest of the thousand requests will handle by a stack or something else, but if you there is kind of limit you that you can just only thousand request so you must handle with your own server where you store count of the API and all.